# PIL Custom Font Alternate Glyphs Not Utilized

Tags: python, fonts, python-imaging-library, truetype, glyph

I made a custom handwriting font and exported it to a .ttf file. The service I used, Caligriphr, allows for alternate glyphs for each character. When I type with the font in notepad, alternate glyphs display correctly. However, when I write text onto an image using PIL with the custom font, only one glyph is used 
    for each character. Below is my code to write on the image:

```
body = ""
with open('body.txt') as fin:
    ls = fin.readlines()
    for l in ls:
        words = l.split(' ')
        for word in words:
            double = random.randint(1,2) == 2
            if(double):
                body += '  ' + word
            else:
                body += ' ' + word
image = Image.open('graph.jpg').convert("RGBA")
text = Image.new('RGBA', image.size, (255,255,255,0))
font = ImageFont.FreeTypeFont('Graphite.ttf', 100)
d = ImageDraw.Draw(text)
d.text(xy=offset, text=body, fill = (26,29,32, 230), font=font)
tilt = random.random() * 2
slt = text.rotate(tilt, expand=1)
sx, sy = slt.size
image.paste(slt, (0,0, sx, sy), slt)
image.save('sample.png')
```

Edit: showing code for how body string is constructed

Any help would be appreciated.

[Alternate Glyphs Displayed in Notepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezv8a.png)

[PIL output not utilizing alternate glyphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AO1Z1.png)

Comment: In your question, you have ```d.text(... text=body...)```, but you didn't show how ```body``` was assigned. Might be relevant.

Comment: Thanks, I edited to show how I created body.

Answer (score 1):

This may depend on whether you're using the original [PIL](https://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) library, or [Pillow](https://python-pillow.org/).

Getting contextual alternate glyphs in the drawn output requires that the rendering engine draw the string as an entire string (not character by character) and, while doing so, process certain data in the font that performs glyph substitutions from the default glyphs.

This data could be OpenType Layout tables in OpenType fonts, AAT tables in Apple TrueType fonts, or Graphite tables in Graphite fonts, depending on what the platform/library supports. Since you mention you got alternates in Notepad, that indicates that the font has OpenType Layout data.

Reading the [Pillow ImageFont](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageFont.html) documentation, it doesn't give any indication as to whether it supports any of these font formats. However, looking at the [Pillow project in Github](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow), I see that [winbuild\config.py] pulls in Harfbuzz, and that would provide support for OpenType Layout data. So, it seems that Pillow ought to draw using the contextual alternate glyphs, though I don't know if anything is needed to trigger it. (In Notepad, it happens by default, but that's not true everywhere.)

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, I think I am using Pillow. Pip freeze shows Pillow==7.1.1 and no reference to PIL.

Answer (score 0):

If using Pillow, you might need to explicitly enable the `Raqm` layout engine when loading the font: "Raqm - A library for complex text layout" http://host-oman.github.io/libraqm/raqm-Raqm.html

This engine can be specified using the `ImageFont.truetype()` function:

```py
font = ImageFont.truetype('Graphite.ttf', 100, layout_engine=ImageFont.LAYOUT_RAQM)
```

Docs: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.truetype

Testing if `Raqm` is availble on your system:

```
>>> from PIL import features
>>> features.check('raqm')
True
```

If not available, on my Ubuntu 20 it installs via

```
$ sudo apt install libraqm0
```

Edit: It looks like you don't even have to specify the `layout_engine` parameter at all. On my system alternate glyphs are used as soon as I install the `Raqm` library, even without changing the code.